# Use git submodules to track remote branches as well as specific tags

Tags: git, git-submodules, gerrit

I have some projects in individual git repositories and an integration repository that includes these using git submodules. The `branch` entry in `.gitmodules` makes it easy to track branches and works together with Gerrit, which I am using, as well as with `git submodule update --remote`. There are a lot of Q&As about that here on stackoverflow.

But too often, one or more of the submodules shall not track a remote branch, but be fixed to a specific tag. I know that I can checkout a tagged revision in the submodule and record that *pointer to tag* with a commit in the integration repository. But even without a value set for the `branch` entry in `.gitmodules`, a subsequent `git submodule update --remote`  changes the submodule that sits on a specific tag, because it defaults to track the `master` branch of submodules without that value set.

Is there a way to specify a tag in the `.submodule` `branch` entry? I did not find a solution for that. Or does this pinning of some submodules to a tag not work at all with `git submodule update --remote`?

May Gerrit's support of submodules offer a solution to this problem? (I have not tried that yet.)